# Export MySQL query results as SQL file

Tags: mysql, sql

10 million rows. Want to backup data in SQL files with 100k rows (breaking the data into chunks). Is it possible to run a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM `myTable` WHERE `counter` > 200000 and `counter` <= 300000  ---> Send to .sql file
```

I want to replace the psuedocode at the end of that statement with real code.

Using the "export" feature of PHPMyAdmin more than 100 times would take too long.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to use the mysqldump command:

```
mysqldump -u root -p [database_name] [tablename]
--where="'counter' > 200000 and 'counter' <= 300000" > [dumpfile.sql]
```

Additional info on the command here:
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html

Answer (score 1):

You can try to use [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysqldump.html) command with script to backup your script.

```
for i in {1..100}
do
    beginRow=$(( ($i - 1) * 100000 ))
    endRow=$(( $i * 100000 ))
    mysqldump -h <hostname> -u <username> -p <databasename>  myTable --where="counter = > $beginRow and counter <= $endRow" --no-create-info > "./data-$i.sql"
done
```